# How to call array data on button onclick using map method in React JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

Hello I am new at ReactJS. I want help i am working on one project using reactjs. In this project I want to implement onClick event in button, I want when button is clicked inside all data should be appear (note:- data should not be appear before button click).

for data I am created one js file in this js file all data is stored in the form of array.

Thanks in advance.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: what is your issue? you need to show your array of data when the button clicked .you must include your code or the screenshots otherwise anyone can't understand what you're asking exactly

Answer (score 0):

Map function passes the current object as the first parameter.

```
{array.map((obj) => {
    return <button onClick={() => handleClick(obj)}></button>
}
```

Now you have obj in the handleClick function. Just get the parameter in the function like

```
const handleClick = (obj) => {
  // Use obj here to access data
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you please share the code because i am still confused.

Comment: You have not provided any code for context so I am a bit unclear on your exact requirements. I have provided the necessary code that made sense. Basically the above code shows how to pass the object to onClick function when using map and the bottom code shows how to capture that object in the handleClick function and use as you want.

Comment: Let me know if I have misunderstood your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**data.js**

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Bulls',
    city: 'Chicago',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Suns',
    city: 'Phoenix',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Magic',
    city: 'Orlando',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Lakers',
    city: 'Los Angeles',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Celtics',
    city: 'Boston',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'Hornets',
    city: 'Charlotte',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'Knicks',
    city: 'New York',
  },
];

export default data;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import data from './data';

function App() {
  const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState();

  const showData = () => {
    setIsShow(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDatas(data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={showData}>Show data</button>

      <div>
        {isShow
          ? datas.map((data) => (
              <p key={data.id}>
                {data.city} - {data.name}
              </p>
            ))
          : ''}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yxamhy?file=src%2FApp.js)